# Azure file share backup lock prevents upgrading AKS version

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-backup-vault

We are using a storageclass in Kubernetes to dynamically provision azure file shares with pvc claims (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv?source=recommendations)

We use recovery service vault to backup these file shares (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/azure-file-share-backup-overview?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Support#key-benefits-of-azure-file-share-backup).

Azure Backup locks the storage account associated with the file shares against deletion in Resource Group scope. The lock is called "AzureBackupProtectionLock" and it protects storage accouunts registered with a Recovery Services vault to guard against deletion of backups.

That seems fair, however this lock on resource group scope is blocking us from upgrading the AKS version. The screenshot with error is attached

[image: Here]

Any idea how to prevent this behaviour ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur if your resource group lock as applied as ***Read only access*** When a resource is marked as read-only, it can only be accessed; it cannot be ***update*** or deleted. By implementing this lock, all authorized users will only be granted the privileges offered by the Reader role.

Please check this [Considerations before applying your locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/lock-resources?tabs=json#considerations-before-applying-your-locks) To resolve this issue make sure to delete our locks in your resource group as below:

***Go to azure portal -> your resource group ->under setting locks -> delete***

[image]

[image]

You need access to **`Microsoft.Authorization/*`** or **`Microsoft.Authorization/locks/*`** operations in order to add or remove management locks. Only ***Owner and User Access Administrator*** have access to those activities among the built-in roles.

***Reference:*** [Lock your resources to protect your infrastructure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/lock-resources?tabs=json)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I reached out to MS support and indeed this is the expected behaviour, you cannot upgrade AKS if rg is locked, so the flow the advise is the following.

1. Delete the lock
2. Upgrade AKS
3. Create the lock again (done automatically by Azure backup)